# VSCode extension activation event onCreate file

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I'm looking for create a extension on vscode but I want to trigger it when someone create a new file. I read the documentation but I find nothing on OnCreate activation event. Somebody know if it's possible to trigger this event ? Or why VSCode don't allow to trigger this event ?

Thanks in advance for the response ;)

Answer (score 0):

As of VS Code 1.29, there is no generic `fileCreated` activation event. Please [file a feature request](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/new/choose) if this is something you want to see

If you are only interested in files of a specific language, use the [`onLanguage:` activation event](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensionAPI/activation-events#_activationeventsonlanguage). This will be fired when a new file is created of a given language.

Otherwise, you can activate on `*`. If you do this, try to defer any extensive operations until they are really needed since your extension will always be activated

Answer (score 0):

There are events on the [workspace](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#workspace) object that one can listen to: [onWillCreateFiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#details-3593) and [onDidCreateFiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/vscode-api#details-3594)